# Not getting path for HTML template

Tags: html, ios, swift

I'm trying to make a PDF in my app. For that I have 3 HTML templates in the app (since it is the HTML file that is finally converted to a PDF). I'm trying to access that template like so:

```
let pathToInvoiceHTMLTemplate = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "invoice1", ofType: "html")
```

But I get the value of `pathToInvoiceHTMLTemplate` as nil. What could be the reason?

Comment: Double check that the invoice1.html is actually added to the main bundle. When you add the file to the project make sure you select copy files if needed and select add to target the application target.

Comment: Did you set the Target Membership for the html files?

Comment: what you are accessing? html or pdf?

Comment: @ Todor Brachkov made sure the copy files were selected and the app target was also selected..but still giving the same issue..

Comment: @Marius Fanu how to set the Target Membership..?

Comment: @PPL I'm accessing html which later on is converted to pdf..

Comment: Make sure you selected your html file (arrow on the left ) then check the arrow on the right https://imgur.com/a/wMzcFCI

Comment: It was already done @Marius Fanu

Comment: Show us a screenshot of your project tree from Xcode that shows invoice1.html.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if html file is also included in Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources  as shown in following screen shot

[image]

As You can see it is here, invoice1.html file is included in main bundle as well as copy bundle resources and also i am getting path in logs. Hope it may help

Comment: Strange...Everything is already as suggested...and that too by default..but still doesn't seem to work..:(

Answer (score 0):

Select your html file in Project, and **Show the File Inspector**, **Target Membership** must be selected like below image

[image]

You can access it later on,

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "invoice1", ofType: "html") {
    //File Exists
}
```

Comment: then there must be other configuration mistake from your side, try to remove file and add file again